# insert into postgresql table jsonb data

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-insert

I  have a table called emp with a column called info as type jsonb

now i want to insert data into it from a table

so it looks like this

```json
{
  "birth": {"date": "1980-04-28"},"Name": {"surname": "James","firstname": "Jacob"}
}
```

I  issue the SQL

```
insert into emp(info)
select 
  row_to_json(x)::jsonb from 
            (select birth_date as date, lastname as surname, given_name as firstname FROM stg.employees) x;
```

but it returns

```json
{
  "date": "1975-11-29T00:00:00",
  "surname": "James",
  "firstname":"Jaconb"
}
```

and not

```json
    {
      "birth": {"date": "1980-04-28"},
      "Name": {"surname": "James","firstname": "Jacob"}
    }
```

could you please point me in the right direction? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into emp(info)
select 
  row_to_json(x)::jsonb from 
            (select jsonb_build_object('date', birth_date) as birth, jsonb_build_object('surname', lastname, 'firstname', given_name) as name FROM stg.employees) x;
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what you've changed and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: thanks Edouard - that worked could you show me how to write it when its nested eg
```
  "currentAddress": {
    "postal": {
   "type": "Street",
      "state": "MI",
        "zipcode": "90801",
      "number": "1",
      "StreetName": "First Ave"
 
                   },
    "residential": {
      "type": "Street",
      "state": "CA",
        "zipcode": "50891",
      "number": "167",
      "StreetName": "Fifth Ave"

    }
}
```

Comment: using `row_to_json` and/or `json_build_object`, you have to iterate as many times as the number of json nested objects. In your last example you have three levels so : `json_build_object('currentAddress', json_build_object('postal', '{}' :: json, 'residential', json_build_object('type', 'Street', 'state', 'NT', 'suburb', 'Darwin', 'postcode', '0801', 'numberlot', '1', 'StreetName', 'Smith', 'unitDetails', '1')))`